# Where is the BOOT1 pin on the STM32F030C8 microcontroller?

Tags: pcb, stm32, bootloader

The datasheet and reference manual for the 'STM32F030x4 STM32F030x6 STM32F030x8' series states that both BOOT0 and BOOT1 pins control the boot mode:
[image]

However, neither the reference manual nor the datasheet states where the BOOT1 pin is located on the STM32F030C8 microcontroller. Does anyone know which pin BOOT1 is located? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

There is no BOOT1 pin at all.

The manual talks about BOOT1 bit which is a programmable bit in user option byte.